# Operations allowed in stateless session bean's business methods

Tags: ejb-3.0, java-ee-5

Given a Stateless Session Bean with a Local Business Interface and CMT (Container Managed Transaction). All methods of the SLSB have Transaction Attribute set to "REQUIRED".

The Bean also has an injected field sessionContext of type SessionContext.

The question is: "Which two operations are allowed in a bean business method?"

According to EJB 3.0 Core Specification, Chapter 4 Table 2:

> SessionContext methods: getBusinessObject,getEJBHome, getEJBLocalHome,
>   getCallerPrincipal, isCallerInRole, getRollbackOnly, setRollbackOnly,
>   getEJBObject, getEJBLocalObject,
>   getTimerService,getInvokedBusinessInterface, lookup JNDI access to
>   java:comp/env

Since this is a question of a simulator for SCBCD (1z0-860) Certification for Java EE 5, the provided answer is:

- sessionContex.setRollbackOnly()
- sessionContext.getBusinessObject()

Other two possible options were "sessionContext.getEJBObject" and "sessionContext.getEJBLocalObject".

Having the SLSB a Business Local Interface, my second choice, after setRollbackOnly was to call getEJBLocalObject which actually is not the right answer.

Is the asnwer provided by simulator correct? If yes:
Anyone can help me to better understand this scenario?

Regards,
Pierluigi

Comment: Was it maybe because the EJBObject and EJBLocalObject is generated by Container in case of EJB 2.1 view? The Question nothing says about this, then it must be assumed that those Session Objects (in this case only the EJBLocalObject, since the interface is local) is not generated at all.

Comment: From JSR 220 EJB 3.0 - EJB Core Contract and Requirements (Chapter 4.3.3): 1) SessionContext.getEJBObject Only Session Bean with Remote Home Interface (thus EJB 2.1 View) can call this method; 2) SessionContext.getEJBLocalObject Only Session Bean with Local Home Interface (thus EJB 2.1 View) can call this method; 3) SessionContext.getBusinessObject Only Session Bean with EJB 3.0 Business Interface (POJO) can call this method. I believe this must be the interpretation of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the given options:

1. **sessionContext.setRollbackOnly** - Can be called because the bean uses container-managed transactions
2. **sessionContext.getBusinessObject** - Can be called because the bean has a business interface
3. sessionContext.getEJBObject - *Cannot* be called because only beans that have a remote component view can call this method
4. sessionContext.getEJBLocalObject - *Cannot* be called because only beans that have a local component view can call this method